# how to show the results of yml file in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

i am learning SWAGGER and Openapi. i downloaded the necessary plugins in visual studio code.
i added the below posted code to test.yml. how to see the results or the output of the code mentioned below.??

i just run the code in visual studio code but nothing appears
please let me know how to show the results of the code posted below.

**code**:

```
openapi: '3.0.2'
info:
  title: Get distance providing start and end GPS coordinates.
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: https://api.server.test/v1
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

Comment: What do you mean by "show the results"? Preview this definition in Swagger UI? Or something else?

Comment: @Helen  how can i get swagger ui please